# Combine scatterplot and barplot, then lapply

Tags: r, ggplot2, lapply

I am trying to add a scatterplot and a barplot within the same plot area with ggplot. The scatterplot should be averages of var. '1' over var.'2' for one dataset, and the barplot should be the average value of '1' over my control dataset.

My data looks like this:

```
> dput(lapply(ubbs6, head))
list(structure(c(96L, 96L, 100L, 88L, 93L, 100L, 61L, 61L, 70L, 
40L, 58L, 70L, 7807L, 7357L, 7695L, 6400L, 6009L, 7735L), .Dim = c(6L, 
3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("1", "2", "3"))), structure(c(99L, 
96L, 100L, 96L, 96L, 96L, 66L, 67L, 70L, 63L, 57L, 62L, 7178L, 
6028L, 6124L, 6082L, 6873L, 5629L, 31L, 27L, 60L, 42L, 12L, 18L
), .Dim = c(6L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("1", "2", 
"3", "4"))), structure(c(99L, 95L, 95L, 100L, 96L, 95L, 69L, 
58L, 56L, 70L, 61L, 65L, 6067L, 6331L, 6247L, 5988L, 7538L, 6162L, 
50L, 36L, 67L, 10L, 55L, 70L), .Dim = c(6L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("1", "2", "3", "4"))))
```

Example of what I've tried so far:

```
 aggregate(ubbs6[[2]][,'1'], list(ubbs6[[2]][,'2']), mean)

m162 <- aggregate(ubbs6[[2]][,'1'], list(ubbs6[[2]][,'2']), mean)
m163 <- aggregate(ubbs6[[3]][,'1'], list(ubbs6[[3]][,'2']), mean)
m161 <- mean(ubbs6[[1]][,'1'])

ggplot(m162, aes_(x = m162[,'Group.1'], y = m162[,'x']))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm', formula = 'y ~ sqrt (x)')
```

I would like to do two things:

1. add a barplot of one x,y value of my control set (ubbs6[[1]])
2. throw this into a lapply structure so I can do this for 11 similar datasets

   Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT: edited out specific details that aren't needed for others to understand the code **

Comment: your provided code is completely unclear. What value should be plotted on the x, which value on the y axis? `Age` or `FPAR` or `dataframe`? Can you include a picture how the plot should look like in the end? Use paint for instance. In additon what is the `control area.`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I have edited my question in the hopes of it becoming a bit clearer. I am trying to compare in this plot the scatter plot of my area 2 (ubbs6[[2]]) to compare with a bar plot of my control area (ubbs6[[1]]). I'll try and add a paint example as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving your data in `d`, you can try

```
ggplot(as.data.frame(d[[2]]),aes(age, FPAR) ) + 
   coord_cartesian(ylim = c(90,100)) +
   geom_point() + 
   geom_smooth(method = 'lm', formula = 'y ~ sqrt (x)') + 
   geom_col(data=data.frame(x=max(as.data.frame(d[[2]])$age),
                       y=mean(as.data.frame(d[[1]])$FPAR)),
                       aes(x,y), inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

[image]

You have to use `coord_cartesian` to specify the y-limits and `inherit.aes = FALSE`. Otherwise the bar is not correctly  drawn.

When you have to combine your second and third dataframe in one plot, you can try

```
library(tidyverse)
d %>% 
  .[2:3] %>% 
  map(as.data.frame) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "id") %>% 
  mutate(max = max(age),
         Mean = mean(d[[1]][1])) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(age, FPAR, color=id)) +
   geom_point() + 
   geom_smooth(method = 'lm', formula = 'y ~ sqrt (x)', se=FALSE) + 
    geom_col(data = . %>% distinct(max, Mean),
             aes(max, Mean), inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, this almost gets me there. I'll mark it as answered because I think that this was the hardest part.

Comment: I think it is not nesseccary to group by the mean before doing the regression. So why are you doing this?